# Is there a ccache or distcc equivalent for .Net and/or mono

Tags: c#, mono, ccache

I've been building rather alot of c# on linux and windows recently, not much of which changes between builds bit it all still takes forever.

When using gcc and g++ I'd get a huge speed benefit from using ccache and to a lesser extent distcc. Are there equivalents for c# compilers on windows or mono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I know of, but you can usually speed up your build significantly by dividing code into smaller assemblies and specifying dependencies between them correctly so that only a small subset of the whole solution gets rebuilt when changes are made.

Comment: but that doesn't help for clean builds, still.. Are there any updates / tools now ?